# Linebreaks in Silex?

Tags: php, silex

one simple question: how do I get working linebreaks in Silex?

Following code will get me the output

```
This ist a Text.<br> Next Line
```

.

```
$app->get('', function () use ($app) {

  $content= 'This ist a Text. <br> Next Line';

  return $app['twig']->render('index.html.twig', array(
    'content' => $content
  ));
});
```

How do i get a working linebreak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [twig escapes everything](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#html-escaping). You can switch off escaping (not recommend) or you can use the [raw](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) filter when echoing:

```
{{ content|raw }}
```

However, another approach would be to use a linebreak instead of the BR element and then use the [nl2br](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/nl2br.html) filter,